# html stream chunking file unknown size

Tags: html, http, audio, stream, http-headers

Hi I would like to stream data from my webserver. 
here is the catch. The data does not exist on my server I retrieve it as a live content from another server. 
So I do not have the size of the file. How do I stream this data.?

I read PCM in chunks (OF DIFFERENT SIZES) convert it to OGG. 
Send the OGG HEADER and the OGG CONTENT down to html5 audio tag
Or at least this is what I want to do.

recap :
I am server "A",

There is another server "B" which servers PCM data.

Client  request comes from an AUDIO tag from HTML5 to server A to get the Data In server B( This data does not have a size,constant streaming).

A recieves PCM from B
Converts to OGG.
Sends it along the http response object as binary data.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/1.1 supports [chunked encoding](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.3.6.1) exactly for this use case.